# Copy different lines of content from text file to clipboard

Tags: batch

I want to run a batch to copy 2 lines of content from a text file but it does not work. It copies both lines of it. Please review and advise what is the correct way to do it. Thanks.

My text file content is (1st line being proxy server and 2nd line is the exception list)

```
sample1.scii.com.uu
*.dh;*.gduu;*.uuarg;10.13.*;10.109.*;10.133.*;*.ehr2.com.uu;*.cldpaast1.hu.org.uu;cims-adi-app-cims-dmz-sit.hu.org.uu
```

My script

```
clip<%~dp0DH_Proxy.txt
start ms-settings:network-proxy
ping /n 6 localhost>nul 2>&1
clip<<%~dp0DH_Proxy.txt
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it what you want, you would need to use a **[`For /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)** loop that receives and echoes each line one at a time from your file:

```bath
@echo off 

for /f usebackq^delims^= %%i in =;(`
find "." ^<"%~dp0\DH_Proxy.txt"`)do =;(
     start "" /b ms-settings:network-proxy
     echo\%%~i|clip & >nul 2>&1 timeout /t 6
    );=
```

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You also can use vbs to type this strings for you

Comment: Do you mean to copy the script and save as vbs ?

Comment: Of course not, it would be [a hybrid bat with vbs](https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-hybrid.html) using [SendKeys](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually simpler than you think:

```
type "%~dp0DH_Proxy.txt" | clip
```

Comment: This copies all content - not that I want.